# Cannot call IO () function even with bang patterns

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have some library which have a function to make plot using gnuplot library:

```
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple

drawMap :: [(Int, Int)] -> IO ()                                                   
drawMap m = do                                                                     
  !a <- plotList [] m                                                              
  print a
```

I call this function from main like this:

```
main = do                                                                          
  !a <- drawMap [(1,2),(3,5)]                                                      
  print a
```

I build project with stack and I've tried -O2 and -O0 optimization, but plot never works (`print a` functions are always called successfully and print `()`).
How can I force plotting and why it doesn't work, with library, but works if I just call `plotList` from main?

**UPD.**

Using strict application in main and in `drawMap` by `$!` doesn't work naither:

```
drawMap :: [(Int, Int)] -> IO ()                                                   
drawMap m = plotList [] $! m                                                                  

main = do                                                                                                                                                 
  drawMap $! [(1,2),(3,5)]
```

**UPD 2**
Some minimal example:

This does not work for me:

```
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple                                                 
                                                                               
main = plotList [] ([(1,2),(3,5)] :: [(Int,Int)])
```

But this works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}                                                  
                                                                               
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple                                                 
                                                                               
main = do                                                                      
  !a <- plotList [] ([(1,2),(3,5)] :: [(Int,Int)])                             
  print a
```

But code from my question does not work even with bang patterns/strict application, if `drawMap` is in other module than `main`.

Comment: `plotList` returns `IO ()`, an action that will do something interesting when executed, but doesn't *provide* any interesting value to bind to `a`.

Comment: @chepner but how can it be enforced? I've tried use deepseq with plotList, but I get an error, that there is no instance of NFData for IO, bang pattenr naither works.

Comment: It _is_ enforced already. The bang pattern or strict application is completely irrelevant, because the `()` value you're forcing (which comes from the `print` in `drawMap`) doesn't have anything to do with the side-effect that's happening or the result of the `plotList` action. — Make this a [MCVE] and explain what you actually need, so the question can be answered.

Comment: Really, I think the problem is `gnuplot`, which is very non-idiomatic for Haskell. Consider using [`dynamic-plot`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dynamic-plot) (disclaimer: I'm the author) or [`Chart`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart) instead.

Comment: What exactly is `plotList` supposed to do? (Clearly an issue on my end, but it doesn't seem to do *anything*, even if I just use `main = plotList [] ([(1,2),(3,5)] :: [(Int,Int)])`.) I would expect `drawMap = plotList []` to work fine.

Comment: @chepner function plotList must to open window with plot, but it does not happen in my example

Comment: @leftaroundabout My example have all you need to reproduce it: I want to get a window with plot, it is what `plotList` function from `gnuplot` do, but in my example window with plot never opens.

Comment: @chepner Try to run your code from `ghci`: it should always work with it and open window with plot

Comment: Could not reproduce. The program given here works fine, and opens a plot. (It does the same without any strictness annotations as well.) Perhaps you do not have `gnuplot` installed?

Comment: @DanielWagner I updated question and post minimal code which works and not works for me. The simpliest version without strictness doesn't works for me, and I have a `gnuplot` installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictness is a red herring. The library is not doing concurrency correctly. Some source diving shows this:

```
runGnuplot ::
   Graph.C graph =>
   [Attribute] -> String -> Plot.T graph -> IO ()
runGnuplot attrs cmd (Plot.Cons mp) =
   void $ Cmd.asyncIfInteractive (interactiveTerm attrs) $ Cmd.run $ \dir ->
      let files = MR.runReader (MS.evalStateT mp 0) dir
      in  (map attrToProg attrs ++
           [cmd ++ " " ++
            extractRanges attrs ++ " " ++
            commaConcat (plotFileStatements files)],
           files)

interactiveTerm :: [Attribute] -> Bool
interactiveTerm =
   all $ \attr ->
      case attr of
         Terminal term -> Terminal.interactive term
         PNG _ -> False
         EPS _ -> False
         _ -> True

asyncIfInteractive :: Bool -> IO ExitCode -> IO ExitCode
asyncIfInteractive interactive act =
   if interactive
     then fmap (const ExitSuccess) $ forkIO $ void act
     else act
```

In particular, when the list of attributes is empty, it will be considered "interactive", and the `IO` action will be forked into its own thread. The semantics of Haskell programs is that they exit when the `main` thread exits, so this is a race condition: will `main` exit first, or will the forked thread call out to `gnuplot` first?

The right thing to do here is for `runGnuplot` to provide the user with an `IO` action that waits for the forked thread to finish that they can call from their `main` thread (for example by allocating an `MVar`, writing to it in the forked thread, and reading from it in the returned action). The simple wrong thing to do is to toss a `threadDelay` into your program:

```
import Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple
import Control.Concurrent

main = do
    plotList [] ([(1,2),(3,5)] :: [(Int,Int)])
    threadDelay 1000000
```

It's still a race condition, but now the forked thread has at least one second to make it to its `gnuplot` call before the program is forcibly destroyed -- [for a computer, that is nearly an eternity](https://youtu.be/h2f54w-1sQE?t=489).